# Collect all indented lines in a list

Tags: r, text, stringr

I have a text file in the following format

```
Information I want:
    info1 a
    info2 b
    info3 c
More information I want:
    info1 1 
    info2 2
    info3 3
```

I want to parse this file in R so that all the indented lines are within the same named vector, within a list.

ie. So that the results looks like the following

```
list(infoIwant = list(info1 = "a", info2 = "b", info3 = "c"),
 otherinfo = list(info1 = "1", info2 = "2", info3 = "3"))
```

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to do this? The only way I can think of would involve a series of if statements dependent on the start of the line, but also maintaining the previous line seems like things would get complicated pretty quick, so looking for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this with a couple `tidyverse` functions. It probably makes more sense to put the data in a plain text file—I just had to use it as a string to use with `reprex` here.

The base `readLines` expects a file or other connection, but `readr::read_lines` lets you read in a string. Again, maybe won't matter in practice. Reading this in gets you a single vector, one entry per line in the file.

```r
library(tidyverse)

text <- "Information I want:
    info1 a
    info2 b
    info3 c
More information I want:
    info1 1 
    info2 2
    info3 3
"

read_lines(text)
#> [1] "Information I want:"      "    info1 a"             
#> [3] "    info2 b"              "    info3 c"             
#> [5] "More information I want:" "    info1 1 "            
#> [7] "    info2 2"              "    info3 3"
```

Convert it to a data frame—I used `as_tibble`, which then gives me a column `value` of that vector. Then I separate it into 2 columns, splitting by the regex `\\s{2,}`, i.e. split where there's 2 or more consecutive spaces. That turns the blank areas into their own entries in the first column.

```r
read_lines(text) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  separate(value, into = c("header", "info"), sep = "\\s{2,}")
#> # A tibble: 8 x 2
#>   header                   info      
#>   <chr>                    <chr>     
#> 1 Information I want:      <NA>      
#> 2 ""                       info1 a   
#> 3 ""                       info2 b   
#> 4 ""                       info3 c   
#> 5 More information I want: <NA>      
#> 6 ""                       "info1 1 "
#> 7 ""                       info2 2   
#> 8 ""                       info3 3
```

But those blanks aren't that useful for working with. Convert the blanks to `NA`, so you can use `tidyr::fill` to fill in any `NA`s in the header column with whatever non-`NA` value comes before it. Filter to remove `NA`s in the info column—those are the places that only had a header but no info, and trim off empty spaces left over in `info`.

```r
read_lines(text) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  separate(value, into = c("header", "info"), sep = "\\s{2,}") %>%
  mutate(header = na_if(header, "")) %>%
  fill(header) %>%
  filter(!is.na(info)) %>%
  mutate(info = str_trim(info))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   header                   info   
#>   <chr>                    <chr>  
#> 1 Information I want:      info1 a
#> 2 Information I want:      info2 b
#> 3 Information I want:      info3 c
#> 4 More information I want: info1 1
#> 5 More information I want: info2 2
#> 6 More information I want: info3 3
```

Lastly, to get a named list from this data frame, you can split the data frame by `header`. That gives you a list of two data frames. If you map over that list and call `dplyr::pull`, you can get just the column `info` as a vector for each list entry.

```r
read_lines(text) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  separate(value, into = c("header", "info"), sep = "\\s{2,}") %>%
  mutate(header = na_if(header, "")) %>%
  fill(header) %>%
  filter(!is.na(info)) %>%
  mutate(info = str_trim(info)) %>%
  split(.$header) %>%
  map(pull, info)
#> $`Information I want:`
#> [1] "info1 a" "info2 b" "info3 c"
#> 
#> $`More information I want:`
#> [1] "info1 1" "info2 2" "info3 3"
```

<sup>Created on 2018-10-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>